# Modify .mdf file from a wpf application using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am using VS2010 , and I am building a simple wpf application using C#
I have built a database using SQL Server 2008

in my application I created a LINQ to SQL class and created a dbml file
then I created a datacontect and did everything right

BUT

when I can't aaccess my database file everytime I try to , I mean when I insert anew row in my datacontexct I can check it and see it but when I look in my mdf file I can't find anything

I think that my datacontexct must be connected to my database file somehow

please help me because I seriously need it

Answer (score 0):

The connection string, that is passed to the datacontext, references the MDF.

```
// Northwnd inherits from System.Data.Linq.DataContext.


    Northwnd nw = new Northwnd(@"northwnd.mdf");

    var cityNameQuery =
        from cust in nw.Customers
        where cust.City.Contains("London")
        select cust;

    foreach (var customer in cityNameQuery)
    {
        if (customer.City == "London")
        {
            customer.City = "London - Metro";
        }
    }
    // you must call this this commit the changes
    nw.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: can I ask you one more question

Comment: where is the mdf file added in your example

Comment: because when I did the same it gave me an error that I can't access my database file , and this error came up when the compiler reached the line : mydatacontexct.submitchanges()

Answer (score 0):

Call `.SubmitChanges()` on your `DataContext` after adding an item.